# Date Time FormatException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, datetime, formatexception

This is a `C#` web service that I am trying to get right.

`arg1` is a drop down menu from where the user can select, Yearly Monthly Quarterly.
`arg2` is the date that they input.
`arg3` is the date that they chose plus either a year, month or 3 months added to the Date.

**So far I have this put together:**

```
public ServiceResult CallService(string arg1, string arg2 = "", string arg3 = "")
{
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

     //Write Your Code Here
     if (arg1 == "1 - Annually")
     {
                
         DateTime thisDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(arg2);
         thisDate1.AddYears(1);
         arg3 = Convert.ToString(thisDate1);
                
     }

     return new EchoInputHandler().EchoInput(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

**I am getting an error:**

```
FormatException was unhandled by user Code
An Exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscor.lib but was not handled in user code
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Could someone educate me on why this is happening?

---

#### Solved

I have solved it! This is what my code looks like now:

```
public ServiceResult CallService(string arg1, string arg2 = "", string arg3 = "")

    {
        if (arg1 == "1 - Annually")
        {
            DateTime arg2Date = Convert.ToDateTime(arg2);
            arg2Date = arg2Date.AddYears(1);
            arg3 = arg2Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is value of arg2

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  Whatever is in `arg2` isn't recognized as a `DateTime` format.  So... What's in `arg2`?

Comment: The value of arg2 is a date, it can be today or any day that they choose. For example 19/08/2015. Day/Month/Year

Comment: What is the exact value of arg2 when you're getting this error?

Comment: @ChristophBethge: `"it can be today or any day that they choose"`... Ok, and what is it when the error is thrown?  Not what *can* it be or what *should* it be, but what *is* it exactly?  Don't guess or assume, *debug*.

Comment: Also the line adding the year needs to be: thisDate1 = thisDate1.AddYears(1);

Comment: @KaiHartmann the exact value is today's date 19/08/2015. Sorry about the previous answer

Comment: Hm, it works for me. Could you try `CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); DateTime thisDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(arg2, culture.DateTimeFormat);` instead of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");`?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but why are you passing in `arg3 ` when you're just recalculating and overwriting it right away?

Comment: arg3 is the value that the webInterface would receive back

Comment: @ChristophBethge I guess I would have to see more of the code, but from what you've posted, I don't understand why `arg3` needs to be a parameter of the method. It would work just as well (and be more clear what the method actually requires to do its job) if it was a local variable.

Comment: @Nik that is all my code. I do understand what you mean with not needing arg3 but i got told that there should be 3 arguments, that's why i use 3. Unfortunately I don't have anyone here to learn from or talk to about these things, that is why I ask here.

Comment: @ChristophBethge In your `CallService` method, you ask for (up to) three parameters: `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`. The passed in values for both `arg1` and `arg2` are read within the method, and that's perfect. However, the passed in value of `arg3` is never used... it is immediately overwritten. The method effectively ignores some of the information the caller gave it. Instead of making `arg3` a parameter, make it a local variable.

Comment: Here's another way of looking at it: You say `arg3` is supposed to be date the user chose plus a year (or some other time period). Let's say I call your method like this: `ServiceResult result = CallService("1 - Annually", "08/20/2015","foobar");` Clearly `foobar` is not the date plus a year, but your method will not crash because the value of `arg3` that I gave your method is never used, it's just immediately overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it tells you that Arg2 could not be recognized as a valid DateTime.

A few enhancements that i would make:

1) Make sure you dont call Convert.ToDateTime on an empty string (use .Parse instead, basically this is what Convert.ToDateTime uses internally)

2) Make sure you validate arg2 - you should know the input format.

3) If you know the input format. Use ParseExact

4) Make sure you use .Parse og .ParseExact with try/catch handling, and return something useful to the client on the catch exception

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime.ParseExact and apply the date format you are trying to use.